# executing magenta with tensorflow architecture problem

Tags: python, tensor, magenta

I have a problem using TensorFlow and Magenta.
I've installed version 1.12 of TensorFlow, version 4.0 of Magenta and Python 3.10, I am using a Mac M1 terminal with and without Rosetta option checked.
When I try to run this command:

```
melody_rnn_generate \
--config=basic_rnn \
--bundle_file=basic_rnn.mag \
--output_dir=/tmp/melody_rnn/generated \
--num_outputs=10 \
--num_steps=128 \
--primer_melody="[60]"
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 0x0006): tried: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/lib/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so' (no such file)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/melody_rnn_generate", line 5, in <module>
    from magenta.models.melody_rnn.melody_rnn_generate import console_entry_point
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/magenta/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    import magenta.common.beam_search
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/magenta/common/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from . import state_util
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/magenta/common/state_util.py", line 18, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.util import nest as tf_nest
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 0x0006): tried: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/lib/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so' (no such file)
```

Any help?